# How to add to eventListener (which deletes item) function that shows the text of this item somewhere else on the page?(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I would like to ask how to add to the eventListener
which deletes item (by accesing its class)
the function that makes this item visible in the other
place on the website.

Code:

```js
const addForm = document.querySelector('.add');
const list = document.querySelector('.todos');

const generateTemplate = todo => {
  const html = `
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span>${todo}</span>
    <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
  </li>`;
  list.innerHTML += html;
};

addForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const todo = addForm.add.value.trim();
  if (todo.length) {
    generateTemplate(todo);
    addForm.reset();
  }
});

list.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e);
  if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
    // how to add here the function which apart from deleting the item
    //can show in the other place (somewhere below)
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #2a0fd7;
  ;
}

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=text]:focus {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 400px;
}

.todos li {
  background: #6c6788;
}

.delete {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <header class="text-center text-light my-4">
      <h1 class="mb-4"></h1>
    </header>

    <ul class="list-group todos mx-auto text-light">
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <span>play mariokart</span>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <form class="add text-center my-4">
      <label class="text-light">Add a new todo...</label>
      <input class="form-control m-auto" type="text" name="add" />
    </form>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Get `e.target.parentElement.textContent`, and use that to create a new element in the other place.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing tag `</div>` just before `<script src="app.js"></script>`

Comment: I just omitted that when copying code but the problem is already solved by Barmar. Anyway thanks